# Dynamic join dependent on if columns are filled out

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have two dataframes and they both contain the same columns I want to join on. However col3 is optional and the logic I want to implement is like so. If all columns are filled out join based on all the columns if not all the columns are filled in join off of the 3 columns.

Code for when all the columns are filled out is simple but I am confused on how I can implement a dynamic join condition.

For the all situation:

```
df1 = (
df1
.join(df2, on=['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'], how='left')
)
```

For the conditional situation I was thinking about leveraging coalesce but this would work for the right side of the table but not too sure about the left side.

```
df1 = (
df1
.join(df2, on=(F.coalesce(df1.col1, df1.col2, df1.col3, df1.col4) == F.coalesce(df2.col1, df2.col2, df2.col3, df2.col4), how='left')
)
```

For example:
df1 is

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col8
 a.    b.   c.   d.   5
 e.    f.   g.   h.   3
 i.    j.   k.   l.   2
```

and

df2 is

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5    col23
a.    b.        d.   type1  there
e.    f.   g.   h.   type2   was
i.    j.   k.   l.   type3    a
```

The end results in this example would be

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
a.    b.        d.   type1
e.    f.   g.   h.   type2
i.    j.   k.   l.   type3
```

Since the first row is missing a value in col3 the join would use col1, col2, and col4 but for the remaining rows it would use col1, col2, col3 and col4.

I have a hard coded way of achieving this by creating hash keys on both sides and using coalesce but wanted to see the communities advice.

I need col5 in df1 or the left side of the join but need to join based on how many columns are filled out. It's almost like joining from most certain match (when all columns are filled in) to least certain match (when 3 out of the 4 columns are filled in).
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Note sure I understand your problem. Can you improve your example please? From where I stand, `return df2` seems like the perfect solution, but I am sure that this is not what you expect...

Comment: @Oli sure thing!